# Trac templating system

Tags: trac

I am trying to understand the templating system. There is a /templating directory with following README:

> It is not advised to make local modifications to those files after installation, as they might be lost during the installation of a new Trac version.
>
> As an alternative, you can copy the templates you want to modify and place them in the templates/ directory of your Trac environment or in the location specified in the trac.ini file under the `[inherit] templates_dir` setting (the former having precedence over the latter).

This would be nice - I could have templates for my project nicely separated in the same path as my project. But this directory contains only part of the templates and for example ticket templates modification is impossible within this path.

So what is the correct way to modify Trac templates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is discouraged in general, because local/custom templates take precedence, and this could come in the way, if upstream releases have significant changes. You'll never get warned about a changed template and you'll have to re-base your template customization on-top of each new template.

Anyway, start from a fresh template copy from source. Templates are to be found in sub-directories `templates` of the respective Trac realm (i.e. `ticket/templates`, `versioncontrol/templates`, `wiki/templates`) and put it to all directly into `<env>/templates` (initially empty) or  for reusing them in multiple Trac environments as per your [inherit] configuration.

Since Trac-0.11 Trac uses the Genshi template engine. See it's [own wiki documentation](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/xml-templates.html) about the available syntax.